# Voting rights for mentally disabled people

Tags: united-states, voting, civil-rights

Can someone enlighten me the rationale behind the fact that mentally disabled citizens are allowed to vote while a 17 year old doesn't have that right, no matter how smart or knowledgeable you are?

Comment: What do you define as "mentally disabled"? Many conditions have no impact on a person's ability to comprehend political issues.

Comment: In Switzerland people "not capable of discernement" (aka mentally disabled) do not get the right to vote. However I do not doubt that for some people with a light disable it can be ambigious whether or not they are allowed full citizenship. I'd belive that if there is any doubt they'd rather give them the right to vote anyway rather than restrict the rights of already disabled people.

Comment: Also, one of the reasons could be that there is a long tradition of various dictatorship regimes to call their opponents "mentally disabled" and to force them in psychiatric institutes.

Comment: I fail to see how this post is something other than an argument; this SE is not in a place to evaluate whether mentally disabled people are more or less deserving of a right to vote than minors.

Comment: The main problen about the question is that two things are compared which can not be compared with each other. What is the age a person should be allowed to vote (differs from country to country), and should people with a mental disabilty have the right to vote?( problem hiw to decide this in generell)

Comment: @ PointlessSpike I'm sure Switzerland has a pretty clear definition of "mentally disabled"

Comment: @chaohuang no, they have a century old definition that is seen as antiquated today: http://www.alzheimer-europe.org/Policy-in-Practice2/Country-comparisons/Legal-capacity-and-proxy-decision-making/Switzerland

Comment: @blip here your go: http://aaidd.org/intellectual-disability/definition#.VcZ6hmhViko

Comment: @chaohuang and your point is?

Comment: @blip the definition

Comment: @chaohuang that's but one definition of one subset of mental disabilities written by one organization. It hardly an all encompassing definition with complete consensus.

Comment: @blip well, by the same token, there is no all encompassing definition of intelligence with complete consensus either. But does that prevent using intelligence measures in political/legal processes (eg IQ cutoff for death enalty)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The existing answer explains the age restriction, so let me focus on the first part of the question.

Voting rights for mentally disabled persons are different in different countries.

In United States, National Alliance on Mental Illness (NAMI) has a Web site that contains some [key information on voting rights](http://www2.nami.org/Template.cfm?Section=Elections1&Template=/ContentManagement/ContentDisplay.cfm&ContentID=137151) for mentally disabled.

U.S. Federal laws protects the right to vote for every person with a mental disability who understands what it means to vote.

> *About 30 states in US have laws in their constitutions that can limit people with mental disabilities from voting if they have been ruled "mentally incapacitated," or incompetent, **by a court**. This means they have been determined unable to manage their own affairs or make specific life decisions, which, other than voting for candidates, can include managing their money, entering a contract, making medical decisions or caring for their children.* — [The Atlantic](http://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2012/10/keeping-the-mentally-incompetent-from-voting/263748/)

As for the reasons why voting rights are often limited for these people:

1. A person who has been ruled by the court of incapable taking decisions, may become **a target of fraud**. Simply speaking, they can be manipulated by someone to vote for a candidate who is a preference for the malefactor, not the voter.
2. Manipulation can be associated with other crimes, like violence or bribery, which is especially violent **against a defenseless person**.
3. This can come to a large scale: consider **a hospice**, for example.
4. **Medicines** used for treatment mental illnesses may produce hallucinations or other kinds of mental disorder. Even sleeping pills can!

In any case, in democratic countries everyone has right to vote. Even someone whose voting right been limited, may appeal — probably, with some legal help from organizations like NAMI.

Yet another thing is that mentally disabled persons usually struggle for survival and don't care much about their voting right. :-(

Comment: Laws prohibiting mentally disabled persons from voting also have little salience to either political party because such persons are unlikely to actually turn out and vote relative to other voters, even if they are legally allowed to do so, and the actual voting choices made by people who are truly impaired so much that they cannot make a meaningful political voice (by definition) are effective random. Hence, these voters tend to cancel each other out on average except to the extent that they actually can make a meaningful choice that is not just random. A fix would be expensive with no impact.

Answer (score 9):

The rationale is that the age limit is easy to define.

We could debate *why is age 18* the age we decided upon but that's a different topic. At least that's a criteria we can apply equally to everyone.

There is no specific definition for 'mentally disabled'. Plus, just because someone may fall into that category doesn't mean they don't deserve equal opportunity at representation.

Bottom line, the age restriction is something we can apply equally to everyone. The 'mentally disabled' label is not.

Comment: And there is presumably a lot more teenagers than there are mentally ill people, so in a sense the mentally ill voting block just matters less.

Answer (score 2):

Young people are easy to manipulate and find it difficult to compromise. As the Pope Benedict XVI said political positions that promotes a very black-and-white picture of human society and rules out any compromise have disastrous results. Young people tend to hold these black-white political positions.

For example the [genocide in Cambodia was orchestrated by young people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khmer_Rouge) that came back from studies in Europe. They were killing anyone who dared to complain about the social changes they were enforcing. Another example would be [Red Guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Guards_(China)) in China. It was a fanatic student mass, patrolling the streets and attacking conservatives. In Germany NSDAP was supported by the young people. [The average age of those joining between 1925 and 1932 was slightly under twenty-nine](http://www.johndclare.net/Weimar6_Geary.htm). Personally I would rather advocate for rising the minimum age when you are eligible for voting to 30 or maybe even 35.

The term mentally disabled can be overused. It would be extremely difficult to agree on the definitions. In Soviet Union conservatives that believed in God and opposed progressive regime were diagnosed with [Sluggish Schizophrenia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sluggish_schizophrenia) and deprived of public rights. In United States the political opponents of Donald Trump were accusing him of mental disorder.

Striping mentally disabled out of voting rights open the doors for systematic abuse. The number of mentally disabled people that vote is negligible, but limiting their public rights could have dire consequence in the future, once the precedent is established.